# Getting an error while loading data into WKInterfaceTable

Tags: swift, xcode6, watchkit

I create a watchKit app/extension of my app. I use this func to load the data into the `WKInterfaceTable`:

```
// Load table into the data
func loadTableData() {

    let sharedDefault = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.Devpr.App")
    let numberItems = sharedDefault?.objectForKey("numberItems") as? Int

    tableView.setNumberOfRows(numberItems!, withRowType: "Cell")

    var i = 0

    let task = sharedDefault?.objectForKey("\(i)WK") as? String
    let row = tableView.rowControllerAtIndex(i) as! TableRowObject  // Get a single row object for the current item
    row.lblTblRowItem.setText(task) // Set the row text to the corresponding item
    i++ // Move onto the next item
}
```

The app is crashing in this line of the function: `let row = tableView.rowControllerAtIndex(i) as! TableRowObject` with this error: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`. I really can't find anything which is `nil`.

Image after the crash:
[image]

I hope someone of you can help me to solve this. Thanks a lot for you're help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If numberOfItems is 0, tableView.rowControllerAtIndex(i) can be nil.

Comment: No, it wasn't the reason.

Comment: Is TableRowObject the table row controller class for rowType "cell"? You may want to po tableView.rowControllerAtIndex(i) and see whether it can be casted to TableRowObject

Comment: Ohh. I didn't set the identifier "Cell" in the storyboard. Thanks a lot for you're help!

Comment: Maybe you'll also have a solution for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30545847/change-color-of-row-programmatically-in-watchkit.